# Difference between Oracle Internet Directory and Oracle Access Manager

Tags: oracle

can someone please tell the difference between Oracle Internet Directory and Oracle Access Manager?
For Single sign on configuration do we need both?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Check this:**

1.https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27559_01/integration.1112/e27123/oidoam.htm#IDMIG30891

1.http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/oim/10.1.4/oam-osso-portal/oam-osso-portal.htm

yes both needs to be present.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Internet Directory is LDAP Server. OID (Oracle Internet Directory ) from OAM perspective contains  the user's data. OAM uses OID as user identity store. But OID is not mandatory, any other LDAP server can be used like AD, DSEE, OVD, OUD.

OAM provides authentication, authorization, single sign on and session management service for web applications (It also supports same for non-web based application).

For more details on OAM : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40329_01/admin.1112/e27239/toc.htm